# Gutenberg Block Development: Trying to add custom js script to npm start command by modifying webpack.config

Tags: block-editor, scripts, configuration

Need help understanding "Provide your own webpack config" https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-scripts/#provide-your-own-webpack-config

```
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config' );

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    entry: {
        ...defaultConfig.entry,
        //index: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src', 'index.js' ),
        slider: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src', 'slider.js' ),

    },
};
```

I am trying here to add a new scipt to the buid folder from src folder while developing a gutenberg block
I get error:

```
ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! slideshow@0.1.0 start: `wp-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-block@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Same for Adding other distinct css file how can I do it?

Comment: If you remove the `slider: ...` part, does it work? Does the full log (from the file) have more details on what is actually going wrong?

Comment: Yes it is working

Comment: Ok, I haven't worked with Webpack in some time, but do you even need a new entry? And are you sure `./src/slider.js` exists and has code in it that doesn't produce errors?

Comment: No I dont think I have an error in the src/slider.js:
console.log('im here too')
import $ from jquery
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
 $('.carousel').slick({
  rtl: true
 });
});
...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! slideshow@0.1.0 start: `wp-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the slideshow@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: Are you trying to have multiple scripts that each get transpiled to their own bundle, with their own map, and their own asset PHP file? AKA having 2 projects but using a single command and webpack not 2?

Comment: I need a distinct front end js file for running a slider on front end; all my back end is done.
I am following Block Editor Handbook doc ( https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/) , but it is not all explained and I am not a npm / webpack expert.

Comment: I import a library: 

import $ from 'jquery'
import 'slick-carousel'
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;

I need these imports to be compiled in a separate file than the index.js

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! I was on it since days!

I found my problem:

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/ helped me to find the solution

Apparently `path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src', 'slider.js' )` was not working:
replacing by simple string path fixed the problem:

```
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config' );

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    entry: {
        ...defaultConfig.entry,
        slider: './src/slider.js',
    },
};
```

Comment: Here is my plugin repository: https://github.com/nextweb-ch/slideshow
Any help would be great especially contributors :)